# Google Maps on Android Emulator Thick Lines

Tags: android, google-maps

Does anyone know how to get rid of these thick lines from Google Maps on an Android emulator? I'm just running the default Google Maps Activity from the wizard (also see it on other projects). When I deploy to an actual device, and not an emulator, the street lines do not look like this.

[image: Google Map zoomed in with thick lines]

If I zoom out far enough, then it goes back to normal

[image: Google Map zoomed out with normal thickness of lines]

Here's the code for the activity

```
    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMapsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap

        val coordinates = LatLng(39.999495, -83.012685)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(coordinates).title("Marker"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coordinates))
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Upgrade to New Map Renderer

There's an existing bug filed in the [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/295677329) about this. And [comment #6](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295677329#comment6) states that this issue is fixed by using the Android SDK `LATEST` renderer / version 18.2 and above (which uses the `LATEST` renderer by default). See more info in (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer).